# Filtrar múltiplos de 3 del arreglo

Tags: java, array, filtro

Estoy tratando de generar un método que sirva para filtrar los múltiplos de 3 de el arreglo, para lo cual he llegado al siguiente código:

```java
public class MultiplosDeTres {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer [] suma = {10, 20, 30, 33, 21, 8, 2, 61};

        for (int i = 0; i < suma.length; i++) {


        }
    }

    public static Integer suma(Integer[] arreglo) {

        Integer resultado = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (Integer num : arreglo) {
            if (num != null) {
                count++;
                resultado += num;
            }

        }

        return (resultado / count);
    }
}
```

Necesito generar este filtro(multiplosde3) para luego sumar sus valores, y que se muestre solo el total de la suma en la consola.

Answer (score 2):

Hay un operador que te da el módulo, o residuo, de una división, para  determinar si un número es múltiplo de otro tienes que obtener el residuo de la división y sólo los números cuyo residuo es cero son múltiplos. El operador que se usa en Java es %.

> Ejemplos:
>
> 14 % 3 = 2 por lo tanto 14 no es múltiplo de 3.
>
> 15 % 3 = 0 por lo tanto 15 sí es un múltiplo de 3.

Para tu ejercicio:

```
public static Integer suma(Integer[] arreglo) {

Integer resultado = 0;
for (Integer num : arreglo) {
    if (num % 3 == 0) {
        resultado += num;
    }
}

return (resultado);
}
```

No creo que necesites hacer un `count` y dividir la suma entre el contadora ya que eso te daría el promedio.

Comment: ¿por qué no son el tipo de preguntas?

Answer (score 2):

*En primer lugar, recomiendo que una variable y un método no tengan el mismo nombre, eso evitará confusiones futuras.*

Por lo mismo he renombrado tu variable `suma` que es un `Array` de tipo `Integer` a `numeros`

```java
Integer[] numeros = {10, 20, 30, 33, 21, 8, 2, 61};
```

Ahora bien para saber si es que un numero en particular, es múltiplo de otro, solo basta con comparar si es que el [resto](https://www.disfrutalasmatematicas.com/definiciones/residuo-resto.html)(*cantidad que sobra luego de una división*) es igual a 0.

```java
if (num%3 == 0) {..}
```

Entonces el código final quedaría:

```java
 public static Integer suma(Integer[] arreglo) {

        Integer resultado = 0;
        int count = 0; //contador
        for (Integer num : arreglo) {
            if (num%3 == 0) { //si es que el resto es 0, el múltiplo de 3
                count++;
                resultado += num;
        }
        //para devolver solo la suma, solo bastaría con resultado, es decir
        // return resultado;
        //pero estás devolviendo el promedio
        return (resultado / count);//resultado dividido por el total de múltiplos (promedio)
    }
```

Para llamar al método solo sería como lo siguiente:

```
System.out.println(suma(numeros));
```